# flutter - set snappings for drag showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable, bottom-sheet, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want to use a modal bottom sheet in the flutter.
but I can't drag it.

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    isDismissible: true,
    enableDrag: true,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: 
    Radius.circular(20),), ),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
     builder: (context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
        stream: controller.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) =>
GestureDetector( behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
 child: Container(
  height: snapshot.hasData
     ? snapshot.data as double
     : pageWidth * .9,
     child: PlayerCardDialog(
 epdId: episodes[index['Ep_ID'])), ),); });
```

can anyone help me please? how can I drag the bottom sheet and how can I set snapping for it in four positions ([0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.0]).

like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can user [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html).
use the `snap` and `snapSizes` for snapping.

However, I think snapping is [added](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/84394) in the `master` channel of Flutter so if you can't find it you may need to [switch to `master`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#switching-flutter-channels).

Or you can check the [snapping_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/snapping_sheet) package.

#### Edit: Example with `showModalBottomsheet()`

```dart
void showBottomSheet(context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        snap: true
        // snapSizes: TODO
        expand: false,
        builder: (context, scrollController) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: Stream.empty(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) => GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              child: Container(
                height: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data as double : 500 * .9,
                child: Text('Test'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: cant do it with showModalBottomsheet ? becuse I need  `height: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data as double : pageWidth * .9` this part for dynamic height.

Comment: @stysh it's a widget and `showModalBottomsheet()` needs a widget, so yes you can. Just return the `GestureDetector` in its builder.

Comment: actually, I've used it. would you please help me? I don't understand your idea.

Comment: it's not work :( and `snap: true
        // snapSizes: TODO` has error